# Can we use external parties as objects in a sequence diagram?

Tags: object-oriented-design, uml, sequence-diagram

I am currently building a sequence diagram for a website to allow customers to make online bookings for a travel agency. If a customer books a flight, he/she can use an online payment method to pay for the ticket. Here the bank is an external party. So can I use bank as an object?

Comment: Of course. It's very useful. Why wouldn't you?

Comment: `Here the bank is an external party.` the bank will provide you with a gateway, so you will have a piece of code, in your system, representing the bank. Use that component.

Answer (score 5):

Formally, the UML specifications require  that the lifelines in a sequence diagram belong to an enclosing classifier. This means that the objects are inside the system and not external to it.

However, it is a popular and well accepted practice to use also lifelines that correspond to actors outside the system. This is somewhat ambiguous since the precise semantic of messages sent by/received by humans are not defined, but it is a pragmatic and approach.

Moreover you could always zoom out of your current system and consider the sequence diagram to relate to a larger enclosing system (e.g. a system of systems) to capture interactions beyond your system’s boundaries.